# "Message from debugger: Terminated due to code signing error" when debugging a Mac app?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I'm writing a Mac app in the sandbox, and can't seem to get code signing to work. I've selected "Developer ID" from the Info tab for my target, and I've tried letting Xcode set up my provisioning profile automatically as well as creating the profile myself. The app builds without any errors or warnings, but when I try to "build and run," it gives me the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `console.app`, I noticed I was getting the following message:

```
3/5/15 4:46:37.151 PM taskgated[73]: killed com.nateparrott.Boxcar[pid 27408] because its use of the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement is not allowed (error code -67050)
```

It turns out that the default entitlements file in my project included an empty list of iCloud container, which caused the sandbox to *think* the app needed iCloud permissions (which weren't included in the default provisioning profile). Removing the iCloud entry from the entitlements file solved the problem.

Comment: I had the same issue with another permission.

Comment: These are the steps I solved this: 1) I removed all the CloudKit-related entitlements to get the app running 2) Reset the certificate 3) Add the entitlements back

Comment: I had this come up with unit testing specifically, and the fix in this case was to change the signing certificate on the test target from the default ("sign to run locally") to "Development".

Answer (score 0):

Try to regenerate your certificates from the Dev Center. This happens most of the times when you switch to a new mac or after upgrading to a newer OS X version.

Comment: I just created my certificates today! (on the same computer)

Answer (score 0):

- You have downloaded and installed your cert (in Keychain Access)  from the portal. If you created the cert today on the same Mac you're trying to run it on this won't be your issue.
- Your cert from above is in the provisioning profile you imported into XCode.
- You actually imported your provisioning profile into XCode. It should be selectable form your Build Settings drop-down.
- The bundle identifier you created in the portal matches what you have designated in your project under the Target Info.

Comment: Pretty sure I've covered all these bases. Could the fact that I'm using a provisioning profile with a wildcard App ID be the problem?

Comment: As long as your app's bundle identifier falls within the wildcard setup you should be fine. IE: "com.mycompany.*" will work with "com.mycompany.foo". Likewise "com.mycompany.myapp.*" will work with "com.mycompany.myapp.foo".

Answer (score 0):

I tried Setting Build Settings->code signing identity to "**Mac Developer**" and Provisioning Profile to "**Automatic**". The debugger worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

This also can happen when debugging on iOS Simulator, when developing for Mac Catalyst, when `ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME` set to `YES`.

Below Xcode configuration helps to avoid this error:

```
ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME[sdk=macosx*] = YES
ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = NO
ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME[sdk=iphoneos*] = NO
```

Answer (score 0):

modify targets>Build Setting>code signing identity to your sign development.

Comment: Please use `*` brackets to change the path's font into italic.