# Mac OSX App : How to test a production build correctly?

Tags: xcode, macos, testing, provisioning-profile, production

There are certain features that I need to test on my Mac OSX App that is going to be only available on the production build. However, I keep getting this error  `Message from debugger: Terminated due to code signing error`. I am trying to use my distribution provisioning profile, but it isn't working. Developer one works fine however. I tried "Save for Mac App Store Development", "Export as a Mac Installer Package", "Export as a Mac Application" and running it through Xcode. None of it works, it keeps crashing due to code sign error. I've been stuck on this for hours. Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: Can you post output from console.app?

Comment: If you are trying to create a Release version for that testing, then you will need to sign it with a valid Apple Developer account with a macOS Developer certificate.

Comment: For the specific error (`Message from debugger: Terminated due to code signing error`), it could be something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803510/message-from-debugger-terminated-due-to-code-signing-error-when-debugging-a-m